# I can't upload application more than 200MB to Mobile Center. How to resolve it?

Tags: microfocus-mobile-center

We are testing gaming application which usually bigger than 200MB.
When I upload it to Mobile Center, It alert me an exception.

Is there any resolution to overcome this?

Comment: hi, post here this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of server stability consideration. Mobile Center set the limitation for application upload size.
If you are using latest version(2.53), there is a private fix at below link for increase the limitation from 200MB to 400MB.
tinyurl.com/ycxfxz6k

For sure we are working on improve the application uploading procedure. Future release we will support uploading bigger application by default.